# How the inequality $\frac1{n+2} \leq \left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right|$ holds?

Tags: combinatorics

$\begin{align*}\frac{n!}{e}-!n&=n!\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\\&=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(1-\frac1{n+2}+\frac1{(n+2)(n+3)}-\cdots\right)\end{align*}$

and hence

$$\frac1{n+2} \leq \left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right| \leq \frac1{n+1}$$

I can understand how$$ \left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right| \leq \frac1{n+1}$$

is but can't understand how the inequality $$\frac1{n+2} \leq \left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right| $$ is true.

Please HELP.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the notation $!n$.  What does it mean?

Comment: $!n$ is derangement.

Comment: Which is a term that holds no mathematical meaning for me.  Could you provide a short formula?

Comment: [derangement wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#cite_note-5)

Comment: Never mind, found the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Let me call $\left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right|=M$. Can you now please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation and your answer are correct, and only one minor piece of detail is helpful in guaranteeing the result:

$${1\over n+2}\le |{n!\over e}-!n|\le {1\over n+1}\tag{1}$$

The far LHS of $(1)$ is shown by the following condition:

$${1\over n+1}-{1\over (n+1)(n+2)}+{1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\dots$$

$$=\left({1\over n+1}-{1\over (n+1)(n+2)}\right)+\left({1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-{1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}\right)\dots$$

$$={1\over (n+2)}+{1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+4)}+\dots\ge {1\over n+2}$$

The argument is very similar for the far RHS of $(1)$, except that the sign of the terms in the sum is switched due to the sum being grouped after the first term instead of immediately.

The grouping of terms is a viable technique as all sums are absolutely convergent.

The absolute value, of course, takes care of the $(-1)^{n+1}$ in the way that you pulled it out very effectively.

Answer (score 2):

I think $$\frac1{n+2} \leq \left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right|$$ is because $$\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{1}{n+2}$$ and there are many many terms to add in $\frac{1}{n+2}$ so it is less than $\left|\frac{n!}{e}-!n\right|$.

Is my answer correct?

Please verify!

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct.  In particular, you have demonstrated the first step, and the following steps are similar.  Since the sum is absolutely convergent, you can rearrange all terms in pairs like you have done, noting (for example) ${1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-{1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}={1\over (n+1)(n+2)(n+4)}$.  In general, all these terms will have positive coefficients, and the $n+k-1$ term will be canceled from each.  The same argument applies for $1\over n+1$, since the sign of the following combined terms is reversed.